# Сумма цифр суммы цифр числа, пока число не станет однозначным на питоне

Tags: python, циклы, рекурсия

На вход программа получает число, которое нужно сократить до одной цифры.

Например, сумма цифр числа 38578324323 равна 48.   У 48 сумма цифр — 12, а у 12 — 3.

Как решить?

Начал решение как-то так:

```
num = int(input("Введите целое: "))
sum = 0

while (len(sum) >= 1)
    while (num != 0):
        sum = sum + num % 10
        num = num // 10
```

Comment: Добавьте пример своей попытки, а то вопрос закроют как "учебный" :) Тут без рекурсии можно, просто через `while`. Суммировать можно через функциональную магию типа: `print(sum(map(int, '38578324323')))`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нерекурсивное решение с использованием [моржового (`walrus`) оператора](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), появившегося в Python 3.8:

```
def sum_dig(n):
    while (n := sum(map(int, str(n)))) > 9:
        pass
    return n
```

Или обычный вариант:

```
def sum_dig(n):
    while n > 9:
        n = sum(map(int, str(n)))
    return n
```

Comment: не совсем понимаю, что значит map(int, str(n)), нужно ли оно, если я ввожу число через консоль и сразу преобразую в int?

Comment: @Alex, чтобы понять что здесь происходит - поэксперементируйте: `n=6745; print(list(map(int, str(n))))` ;) В приведенных мною решениях число сначала преобразовывается в список целых чисел - цифр числа, для простоты суммирования

Answer (score 4):

Вот простенькая рекурсивная функция:

```
def sum_digits(n):
    r = sum(map(int, str(n)))
    return sum_digits(r) if r > 9 else r

print(sum_digits(38578324323))
```

---

Малопонятный рекурсивный однострочник для <s>извращенцев</s> любителей прекрасного  ([работать будет только в Python 3.8+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)):

```
def sum_digits(n):
    return sum_digits(n) if (n := sum(map(int, str(n)))) > 9 else n
```

Answer (score 3):

есть еще "читерский" способ

> The digital root (also repeated digital sum) of a natural number in a given radix is the (single digit) value obtained by an iterative process of summing digits, on each iteration using the result from the previous iteration to compute a digit sum. The process continues until a single-digit number is reached. In base 10, this is equivalent to taking the remainder upon division by 9 (except when the digital root is 9, where the remainder upon division by 9 will be 0).

то есть:

```
num = int(input("Введите целое: "))
sum_ = 9 if not num%9 else num%9
```

отсюда https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_root

Comment: wow, этот метод прекрасен! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_digits(n):
    return (n - 1) % 9 + 1
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]